# Plugin to Link Posts by Title

Tags: plugin-recommendation, links

I'm looking for a plugin that will allow me to link to posts by title. That is, when I click the link icon in the editor (or some other icon), instead of entering a URL, I get a drop-down of posts to link. I select one, press okay, and tada! Link is done.

I also expect that the link looks at the ID; so if I change the target page's title, post-slug, or any other features that may be in the permalink, the link is "smart enough" to still link the correct page.

Does anything like this exist out there? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEO Smart Links does an amazing job for this. It provided exactly what I wanted.

Originally, I used [RB Internal Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rb-internal-links/). It only works through the visual editor, though.